# Why is **/* used to search recursively through current directory in :vimgrep vim command?

Tags: regex, vim, glob, vimgrep

Why do they use the double asterisk?

I've read Vim's help on `vimgrep`, I've looked around on stack overflow and vimcasts and whilst I have found lots of people saying that this is **how** you search recursively in current directory, I haven't found an explanation as to **why**.

Lets use an example to make it easier to explain. If I wanted to find all occurrences of foo in my current directory and down, I could use

```
:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file}
```

so that becomes

```
:vimgrep /foo/ **/*
```

So looking at the `{file}` part of this grep:

- I understand that it is a file path.
- I understand that an asterisk (`*`) is a wildcard.
- I understand that the forward-slash acts as a
  directory separator.

My specific question is why it comes in the format of

`**/*`

and not

`*/*`

I've tried searching using */* in a few different cases and that seems to search any file in any directory exactly 1 deep from my current directory, which I assume is why double asterisk is used.

ie Why is it a double asterisk? Does this indicate "I want you to search recursively" through some clever mechanisms I don't fully understand or is this just simply a keyword that serves to say 'search recursively'? Am I completely off and this is not an inbuilt part of vim but a part of the shell? (these parts are not my actual question but rather serve to give understanding as to what I am confused about, my actual question is above).

If there are any ways I can improve my question, please let me know, it's my first time asking.

Comment: I will never cease to be amazed by vim's help files. It didn't even occur to me that I could just do this. However I would still very much appreciate a lengthy answer demonstrating that vast knowledge, just to bask in the many useful bits of information.

Comment: That came from [advanced Unix shells](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#globstar_.28since_bash_4.0-alpha.29).

Comment: @phd FWIW, `**` has been in Vim [since 2005](https://github.com/vim/vim/commit/027436338b4b3e746ae5087b8a01c7404619d97b) whereas bash has it [since 2009](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver4.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Short answer:**

The double asterisk is a vim build-in keyword, which simply says 'search recursively'.
It is used, because the creator of vim choosed to use it for this case.

### **Longer answer:**

There are two different cases, where `**` is used: file searching and the rest.

Vim help explains this very well.

For the 'rest' see `:help wildcard` and `:help starstar-wildcard`:

From `:help wildcard`:

> **      matches anything, including nothing, recurses into directories

and `:help starstar-wildcard` specifies:

> Expanding "**" is possible on Unix, Win32, Mac OS/X and a few other
>   systems.   This allows searching a directory tree.  This goes up to
>   100 directories deep.

---

For file searching see `:help **` or `:help starstar`.

To quote the relevant parts (emphasis mine):

> The file searching is currently used for the 'path', 'cdpath' and
>   'tags' options, for finddir() and findfile().  Other commands use
>   wildcards which is slightly different.

[...]

> Downward search uses the wildcards '*', '**' and possibly others
>   supported by your operating system.  '*' and '**' are handled **inside** Vim,
>      so they work on all operating systems.

[...]

> '**' is more sophisticated:
>         - It ONLY matches directories.
>    - It matches up to 30 directories deep by default, so you can use it to
>           search an entire directory tree
>         - The maximum number of levels matched can be given by appending a number
>           to '**'.